# css selector: exclude input/textarea elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I try to simple disable text selecting on the page, except input fields like `<input>` or `<textarea>`

```css
*,
::selection {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="text" />
<input type="number" value="69420" />

<textarea>
foo bar
</textarea>

Foo bar text on the site
```

I wanted to use the [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not?retiredLocale=de) selector since, writing every rule for every input element seems a bit hacky, and a explicit exclusion seems a better approach.

So i tried the following:

```css
*:not(input):not(textarea),
::selection::not(input):not(textarea) {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

The problem is, the css above does simple not work. You can select whatever you want.

How can i exclude input/textarea elements from the css selector in the first snippet?

EDIT:

I just discoverd, when i remove the pseudo selector `::selection`, the `:not()` selector works:

```css
* :not(input):not(textarea) {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Keep it open, perhaps some one has a better solution / can add some explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`::selection` should be at the end of the selector:

```css
*:not(input):not(textarea),
:not(input):not(textarea)::selection {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="text" />
<input type="number" value="69420" />

<textarea>
foo bar
</textarea>

Foo bar text on the site
```